# Can't access public samba share: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, samba, nas

I don't get a public samba share working. This is really giving me some headache. I'm trying to have a private share, that authenticates with a password for specific user (this part is working fine) and a public share, that everyone in my network can access and write to. But I can't mount it. I'm not getting a password prompt but also no access to it. What I'm doing wrong here?

`testparm` is giving me following output:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix extensions = No
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[Nas]
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    path = /mnt/nas/nas
    read only = No
    valid users = myuser
    wide links = Yes


[Home]
    create mask = 0777
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /mnt/nas/share
    read only = No
```

In Linux I try following command to access the share:

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs -o guest //my.nas.server/home /mnt/share/
```

but it fails because of

> mount error(13): Permission denied

With windows no luck either.

#### Update:

The output of:

```
ls -al /mnt/nas

drwxrwx---  5 myuser myuser  4096 Sep 13  2021 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jun  9  2022 ../
drwxrwx--- 16 myuser myuser  4096 Jan 23 15:58 nas/
drwxrwxrwx  3 nobody nogroup 4096 Jan 23 16:52 share/
```

Comment: Add to your post the output of the following command on the server: `ls -al /mnt/nas`

Comment: @Morbius1 I updated the requested information.

Comment: Could you clarify the following: are you trying to access from Ubuntu a Nas share on a separate machine (in which case the Samba definition does not come into play) or define a specific area of your Linux machine as a share (in which case the 'mount" has to be done on another machine)?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I define 2 areas of my machine as shares. One with access restriction and one without.

Comment: So, you mount these areas on the machine where they are defined.  What is the purpose?

Comment: Of course not. I'll mount it with any machine in my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux file system is hierarchical. If you put a road block anywhere along the path to an object it will prevent anyone access to that object.

On your server the /mnt folder allows everyone to pass but your /mnt/nas folder allows only "myuser" to pass so only that user can get to the /mnt/nas/share folder.

2 possible options:

***Change the permissions of /mnt/nas:***

```
sudo chmod o+x /mnt/nas
```

***Or change your share definition for [Home] to make your guest user appear to be "myuser":***

```
[Home]
    create mask = 0777
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /mnt/nas/share
    read only = No
    force user = myuser
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

You might want to do this anyway since if the guest user (nobody) adds a file to the share it will be owned by "nobody" and "myuser" will not be able to do anything with it. With "force user = myuser" all files added will be owned by "myuser".

Comment: For clarification: I need to give /mnt/nas folder the execute permission so that users that are not 'myuser' or in 'myuser' group can request access to /mnt/nas/share?

Comment: And thank you very much. Today I really learned something.

Comment: Your first comment to my answer was a very succinct explanation, yes.